# QuickSelect won't pass value

Tags: javascript, jquery, quickselect.js

I'm using the [QuickSelect jQuery plugin](https://github.com/dcparker/jquery_plugins/tree/master/quickselect) to implement a very simple "type to select" dropdown box for a city selection. I've got it working visually, but I cannot get it to pass the `value` field rather than the `label` field when submitting the form.

I have a simple input box on an HTML form:

```
<input name="city" id="IDX-qsCityList-28052" placeholder="City"/>
```

My JavaScript code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#IDX-qsCityList-28052").quickselect({
        maxItemsToShow:10,
        data: [
            {
                label: 'Boston',
                value: '1234'
            }, {
                label: 'Atlanta',
                value:'382'
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: It is a 5 years old library, why don't you just use jquery-ui autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

[Solution](http://jsbin.com/vezewo/1/edit)

I edited the quickselect library file `jquery.quickselect.js` at line 109 to store the value at "QuickSelect" data attribute. This way you can retrieve the value you need with:

```
$("#IDX-qsCityList-28052").data('QuickSelect');
```

The library edited raw code at github: https://github.com/rafaelcastrocouto/jquery_plugins/blob/gh-pages/quickselect/jquery.quickselect.js

The working link if you wanna test it out: http://rafaelcastrocouto.github.io/jquery_plugins/quickselect/jquery.quickselect.js

Comment: thank you for the input on this. The value is getting passed via the form. How do I pass it as a form variable?

Comment: there are some ways ... a simple one is to create a hidden input and update it's value.